# Angular 2: Extracting json fields into an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following json data and want to extract unique vendor fields into an array. How do I accomplish this in angular2 component.

Here is my data:

```
[{"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Flexsteel"},
{"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Klaussner"},
{"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Flexsteel"},
{"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Craftmaster"},
{"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Craftmaster"}]
```

and I want the resulting array to show:

```
[{"vendor": "Flexsteel"},
{"vendor": "Klaussner"},
{"vendor": "Craftmaster"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const data = [...your data...];

const vendors = data.map(d => {
  return { vendor: d.vendor };
});
```

Comment: I am getting a error on "vendor" where you have {vendor: d.vendor}. It is saying "unused label". I am not sure what that means.

Comment: Oh, sotty...brackets for an object in lambda expressions...no good idea -> Updated answer

Comment: This works. Is there a direct way to extract unique vendors or do I have to write a function to do this?

Comment: const unique = [...Array.from(new Set(vendors.map(v => v.vendor)))];

Answer (score 2):

You can just use Array.map:

```
let data = [
        {"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Flexsteel"},
        {"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Klaussner"},
        {"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Flexsteel"},
        {"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Craftmaster"}
      ];
let processedData = data.map(dat => ({ vendor: dat.vendor }));
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get the vendors, you can get it like this:

```
let data = [{"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Flexsteel"},
            {"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Klaussner"},
            {"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Flexsteel"},
            {"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Craftmaster"}];

// Get all the vendors 
let vendors = data.map(dat => ({ vendor: dat.vendor }));
```

After that you'll need to filter the vendors and get only unique vendors using:

```
// Unique Vendors 
let uniqueVendors= Array.from(new Set(vendors.map((x) => JSON.stringify(x))))
                                             .map((y) => JSON.parse(y.toString()));
```

Full code snippet:

```js
let data = [{"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Flexsteel"},
            {"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Klaussner"},
            {"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Flexsteel"},
            {"category": "Living Room", "vendor": "Craftmaster"}];

// Get all the vendors 
let vendors = data.map(dat => ({ vendor: dat.vendor }));

let uniqueVendors= Array.from(new Set(vendors.map((x) => JSON.stringify(x))))
                                             .map((y) => JSON.parse(y.toString()));
                                             
console.log(uniqueVendors)
```